# How to access constant variables (defined in another file) dynamically in a function?

Tags: php, variables, constants

I have a file that defines constant variables, like this:

**define_vars.php**

```
<?

define("something","value");
define("something1","value");
define("something2","value");
define("something3","value");
```

And I have a function which parses `$var` as the constant variable name, like this:

```
function something($var=''){

include('define_vars.php');

// $var is the name of one of the variables I am defining in the other file (define_vars.php)
// So $var may have a value of "something3", which is the name of one of the constants defined in the other file...

}
```

I need to somehow get the value of the constant, when $var holds the name of the constant I wish to get the value of....make sense? :S

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `constant()`

```
constant($var); // value
```

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/constant

```
function something($var) {
    if (defined($var)) {
        $value = constant($var);
    }
}
```

Also you should make sure that the file with the definitions gets included only once, so use `require_once('define_vars.php');` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use [constant()](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to get the value.  You could do something like this

```
function something($var = '') {
    include_once('define_vars.php'); //you don't want to include the file more than once or it will cause a fatal error when trying to redefine your constants
    return (defined($var) ? constant($var) : null);
}
```